# A case when to produce an 'in' statment

Tags: sql-server, case

I would like to use a case when to finished an 'in' statement, something like:

```
Select * from table where date in (case when table.comp = 'LPC' then '01/10','01/07' else '01/10' end)
```

So that if the company is LCP I will pull out all records where the date is either 01/10 or 01/07 and any other I just get the records where date is 01/10.
The statement doesn't work and the error is at :

```
then '01/10','01/07'
```

Is the a way of getting an 'in' statement to work with a select case?

Comment: I just found another answer for this question. It is closed.

Answer (score 0):

> So that if the company is LCP I will pull out all records where the date is either 01/10 or 01/07 and any other I just get the records where date is 01/10.

The following expression is a concise (and syntactically valid) way to do what you want:

```
where date = '01/10' or (table.comp = 'LPC' and date = '01/07')
```